# "Too many arguments" error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

Here's my script:

```
if [ awk '$0 ~ /Failed/ { print }' $(pwd)/unity.log ]; then
    echo "Build Failed"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Build Success"
    exit 0
fi
```

The gist is that I am checking the file for "Build Failed" message and exiting 1 if failed.

If what I understand is correct, `awk` will return blank string if there is no text in the file and some text if it's found. But it shoots syntax error : `./Scripts/build.sh: line 41: [: too many arguments`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `[]`, use `grep`:

```
if grep -qw Failed unity.log; then
    echo "Build Failed"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Build Success"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `$(pwd)`? Seriously, if the file is in the current working directory, what's the point of appending the full directory name? `$PWD` would give the same result without executing a sub-shell.

Comment: @alvits - I removed it.  It was in the OP's code and that's how it got there.

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the default exit value being 0. Also, there's no reason to do `$(pwd)/filename`; just do `filename`.

```
grep -qw Failed unity.log || { echo "Build Failed"; exit 1; }
echo "Build Success"
```

It would be also more idiomatic to send the error message on failure to `stderr` (with `echo >&2`).

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if [ ! "$(grep 'Build Failed' unity.log)" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Using `[`...`]` and the output of `grep` is wasteful. Just use `grep` as the if condition itself.